# ошибка: перечисления IEnumerable<T> недопустимы в данном контексте

Tags: c#, dapper

Будет несколько многовато кода, но не пугайтесь  =)
В, скажем так, *модели данных* приложения есть ("таблицы") коллекции экземпляров классов, соответствующие неким таблицам БД; обновляются из БД они Dapper'ом, с жёстким указанием класса, в экземпляры которого будет происходить (mapping)размещение результатов запроса -- соответственно, для каждой "таблицы" своя типовая функция, отличающаяся только именем базовой сущности. Естественно, это не красиво, и хочется обобщить

```
public static OracleConnection oracleConnect;//общедоступный коннект к БД Оракл

public ObservableCollection<LOGS> Logs;//"таблица" записей лога
public IEnumerable<LOGS> getLogsRows(string sqlWhere = @"")//функция её обновления
{
    string oracleSelectAllLogs = "SELECT * FROM LOGS " + sqlWhere;
    var getLogs = MNLZContext.oracleConnect.Query<LOGS>(oracleSelectAllLogs);//выбрать всё содержимое табл.
    return (getLogs);
}

public ObservableCollection<TRACK_EVENT> TrackEvent;//"таблица" событий
public IEnumerable<TRACK_EVENT> getTrackEventRows(string sqlWhere = @"")//функция её обновления
{
    string oracleSelectAllTrackEvent = "SELECT * FROM TRACK_EVENT " + sqlWhere;
    var trackEvent = MNLZContext.oracleConnect.Query<TRACK_EVENT>(oracleSelectAllTrackEvent);//выбрать всё содержимое табл.
    return (trackEvent);
}

//неудачная пока попытка "обобщения"
public Dictionary<string, object> dbTables;//набор всех "таблиц", с доступом по имени табл. в БД
public IEnumerable<baseTable> getTableRows(string tableName, string sqlWhere=@"")
{//!собственно ПРОБЛЕМА: тут надо перейти от "baseTable" к чему-то вроде      
    Type tableType = ((ObservableCollection<object>) dbTables[tableName]).GetType();//получим класс сущности элемента перечисления (тип таблицы), надеюсь
 //и далее вместо "baseTable" писать вроде "tableType.GetType()" -- но оно не работает, т.к. перечисления IEnumerable<T> недопустимы в данном контексте  =(
    string oracleSelectAllTableRows = @"SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ' ' + sqlWhere;
    IEnumerable<baseTable> tableRows = MNLZContext.oracleConnect.Query<baseTable>(oracleSelectAllTableRows);//тут будет ошибка "перечисления IEnumerable<T> недопустимы в данном контексте", если пытаться заменить baseTable на tableType
    return (tableRows);
}
```

**JFYI:**
предполагаю использовать это таким образом:

```
dbTables.Add("LOGS", Logs);//"таблицы" в словарь, с доступом по ключу == имени табл. в БД
dbTables.Add("TRACK_EVENT", TrackEvent);

foreach(string tableName in dbTables.Keys)//разом все "таблицы" обновить из БД
{//так работать не будет, это просто примерный набросок
       dbTables[tableName] = new ObservableCollection<baseTable>( getTableRows(tableName) );
};
```

классы сущностей БД:

```
public partial class baseTable : Object //просто базовый класс для всех таблиц БД (пока только: LOGS, TRACK_EVENT)
{
    public int ID { get; set; }//Первичный ключ
}
public partial class LOGS : baseTable  //запись лога
{//...с какими-то полями, это не существенно
}
public partial class TRACK_EVENT : baseTable  //отслеживаемое событие
{//...с какими-то полями, это не существенно
}
```

Вроде бы простой вопрос, но что-то не соображу -- подскажите как вывернуться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что именно Вы хотите получить, то тут без рефлексии не обойтись. И, кажется, Вы чуть-чуть запутались в типах, когда писали свой вариант кода.

Кстати, смотрите: сначала у Вас в `dbTables[tableName]` лежит объект `ObservableCollection<itemType>`, а потом его заменяете на `ObservableCollection<baseTable>`. Это не очень хорошо: такая система выдержит только однократное обновление данных, а на 2-й попытке обновления сломается. Надо бы заменять `dbTables[tableName]` аналогичным по типу объектом. Предлагаю возвращать из метода `getTableRows()` не `IEnumerable<baseTable>`, а сразу `ObservableCollection<itemType>`. Ну а поскольку мы заранее не знаем, каким типом будет уточнён возвращаемый `ObservableCollection<>`, то сама функция будет возвращать `object`.

В итоге предлагаю такой код для метода `getTableRows`:

```
public object getTableRows(string tableName, string sqlWhere = @"")
{
    // взять тип таблицы, сидящей в dbTables[tableName]
    Type tableType = dbTables[tableName].GetType();

    // проверить полученный тип
    if (tableType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
        throw new ArgumentException("Непонятный класс элемента dbTables[tableName]");

    // взять единственный generic-аргумент сконструированного класса ObservableCollection<T>
    Type itemType = tableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // получить обобщённый метод SqlMapper.Query<T>(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
    MethodInfo generic_method = typeof(SqlMapper).GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Query"))
        .Where(m => m.IsStatic)
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 7)
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(IDbConnection))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(string))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[2].ParameterType == typeof(object))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[3].ParameterType == typeof(IDbTransaction))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[4].ParameterType == typeof(bool))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[5].ParameterType == typeof(int?))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[6].ParameterType == typeof(CommandType?))
        .Where(m => m.ContainsGenericParameters)
        .Single();
    // создать сконструированный метод SqlMapper.Query<itemType>(IDbConnection, string, object, IDbTransaction, bool, int?, CommandType?)
    MethodInfo constructed_method = generic_method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { itemType });

    // строка запроса
    string oracleSelectAllTableRows = @"SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ' ' + sqlWhere;
    // формируем список параметров для вызова
    object[] call_parameters = new object[]
    {
        MNLZContext.oracleConnect,
        oracleSelectAllTableRows,
        constructed_method.GetParameters()[2].DefaultValue,
        constructed_method.GetParameters()[3].DefaultValue,
        constructed_method.GetParameters()[4].DefaultValue,
        constructed_method.GetParameters()[5].DefaultValue,
        constructed_method.GetParameters()[6].DefaultValue
    };
    // делаем вызов сконструированного метода, чтобы получить новый набор данных 'tableRows'
    // IEnumerable<itemType> tableRows = MNLZContext.oracleConnect.Query<itemType>(oracleSelectAllTableRows);
    // IEnumerable<itemType> tableRows = SqlMapper.Query<itemType>(MNLZContext.oracleConnect, oracleSelectAllTableRows[, null, null, true, null, null]);
    // поскольку вызывается статический метод, то первый параметр .Invoke() ставим 'null' (объекта нет)
    object tableRows = constructed_method.Invoke(null, call_parameters);

    // конструируем тип IEnumerable<itemType>
    Type ienumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { itemType });
    // запрашиваем у типа таблицы ObservableCollection<itemType> подходящий конструктор
    ConstructorInfo constructor = tableType.GetConstructors()
        .Where(c => c.GetParameters().Length == 1)
        .Where(c => c.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsEquivalentTo(ienumerableType))
        .Single();

    // конструируем и возвращаем коллекцию 'new ObservableCollection<itemType>(tableRows)'
    // получение интерфейса 'IEnumerable<itemType>' от объекта 'tableRows' будет сделано без дополнительных усилий с нашей стороны :)
    return constructor.Invoke(new object[] { tableRows });
}
```

Цикл обновления таблиц будет выглядеть так:

```
foreach (string tableName in dbTables.Keys.ToList())
    dbTables[tableName] = getTableRows(tableName);
```

Полный текст программки, в которой проверял код: https://pastebin.com/8UMW3HXy

Comment: Оч.интересно... есть ошибка: при получении обобщённого метода LINQ-выборка возвращает пустоту, выпадает исключение "Последовательность не содержит элементов" на выборке по имени :-( проверил в тестовую переменную `MethodInfo[] generic_methods = MNLZContext.oracleConnect.GetType().GetMethods();` -- просто нет метода с таким именем -- мне кажется потому, что интересующие нас методы **расширения** `Query`(один возвращает результатом жёстко типизированное `<T>` перечисление, другой `dynamic`) -- они оба появляются на стандартном `OracleConnection` из Dapper'а. Как быть?

Comment: ну и параметров у этих методов **расширения** `Query` поболее, 1 это только обязательный, но до этого просто не дошло пока.

Comment: учитывая, что методы Dapper'а расширяют `System.Data.IDbConnection` пробовал просматривать множество `MethodInfo[] generic_methods = typeof(System.Data.IDbConnection).GetType().GetMethods()`, тоже нет такого метода :(

Comment: `typeof(Dapper.SqlMapper).GetType().GetMethods()` аналогично :((

Comment: @Alias, прошу прощения. Я не знал библиотеки Dapper, и рассчитывал на то, что Query<T> - это метод класса, а не метод **расширения**. Сейчас осознал ошибку, загуглил и увидел, что к чему. Тот метод, который вызывается в Вашем коде, нашёл. Загляните через часок-другой, думаю что смогу разобраться и исправить свой ответ. В любом случае благодарю за интересную задачку :)

Comment: @Alias, готово! Отредактирован текст ответа, включая исходный код и ссылку на "контрольную" программку. Проверьте, пожалуйста, будет ли новый вариант кода работать в Вашем приложении...

Comment: метод работает, просто огромное спасибо за это -- но мне надо *обмозговать* :) пока что могу сразу сказать: нельзя сразу возвращать `ObservableCollection<itemType>`, т.к.: (1) `getTableRows(tableName,sqlWhere)` это метод  в т.ч. обновления таблицы;

Comment: и (2)есть *заморочки* со словарём/коллекциями в нём: (А)нельзя класть в словарь не инициализированную коллекцию (потом её тип не взять); (Б)если коллекцию инициализировать как пустую, положить в словарь, а потом переприсвоить `new ObservableCollection<T>`, то при попытке перечисления элементов словаря будет ошибка "коллекция была изменена, перечисление невозможно"

Comment: т.е. оно компилируется и при выполнении присвоится то коллекция как надо -- но при попытке на след.итерации выбрать следующую среди элементов словаря, выпадет описанное исключение; Итого, пока метод возвращает перечисление `IEnumerable<dynamic> getTableRows(tableName,sqlWhere)`, тип которого автоматически подбирается верно (проверено), затруднение возникает при обновлении элемента словаря -- но это тянет уже на отдельный вопрос, если сам не разберусь -- You are Welcome :)

Comment: @Alias, ошибка "коллекция была изменена" правится легко, в моём коде это учтено :) Всего лишь и нужно, что производить перечисление нужно не на самой коллекции ключей, а на  её **копии**, т.е. вместо `foreach (string tableName in dbTables)` я пишу `foreach (string tableName in dbTables.Keys.ToList())` и всё (можно `ToList()` заменить на `ToArray()`, но это не принципиально)